# Python, Sqlite not saving results on the file

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have this code in Python:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("people.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = 'create table if not exists people (id integer, name VARCHAR(255))'
cursor.execute(sql)
conn.commit()

sql = 'insert into people VALUES (3, "test")'
cursor.execute(sql)
conn.commit()   

sql = 'insert into people VALUES (5, "test")'
cursor.execute(sql)
conn.commit()  

print 'Printing all inserted'
cursor.execute("select * from people")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print row

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

But seems is never saving to the database, there is always the same elements on the db as if it was not saving anything.

On the other side If I try to access the db file via sqlite it I got this error:

```
Unable to open database "people.db": file is encrypted or is not a database
```

I found on some other answers to use `conn.commit` instead of `conn.commit()` but is not changing the results.

Any idea?

Comment: your code works perfectly for me

Comment: Seems the code is working now... Any idea on the error Unable to open database "people.db": file is encrypted or is not a database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work alright for me ("In database" increases on each run):

```
import random, sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("people.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = 'create table if not exists people (id integer, name VARCHAR(255))'
cursor.execute(sql)

for x in xrange(5):
    cursor.execute('insert into people VALUES (?, "test")', (random.randint(1, 10000),))
conn.commit()

cursor.execute("select count(*) from people")
print "In database:", cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: To save us from having to compare code, can you explain what you did to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

BINGO ! people! I Had the same problem. One of thr reasons where very simple. I`am using debian linux, error was

> Unable to open database "people.db": file is encrypted or is not a database

database file was in the same dir than my python script
connect line was
`conn = sqlite3.connect('./testcases.db')`

I changed this

`conn = sqlite3.connect('testcases.db')`

! No dot and slash.
Error Fixed. All works

If someone think it is usefull, you`re welcome

Comment: This is very good point. Always check your paths, ie. you run scripts as cron job etc.

Answer (score 3):

You should commit after making changes i.e:

```
myDatabase.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

can you open the db with a tool like sqlite administrator ? this would proove thedb-format is ok. 
if i search for that error the solutions point to version issues between sqlite and the db-driver used. maybe you can chrck your versions or AKX could post the working combination.

regards,khz

Comment: Hi hhz, is ubuntu server so I don't have UI. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: scp it to a client with ui . possible ? would just letyou be sure if .db file itself is valid.